# Differential Data Merge is complex? How to get results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, set-difference

I am looking at an old stored procedure that's job is to preserve the New sort order based on yesterday's and today's data.

Sort orders are not being preserved any longer and I have narrowed it down to the `WHERE` clause eliminating all rows. The main goal is to preserve the `SortOrder` so if some custom data was in position 4 yesterday, any NEW custom data that takes its place should ALSO have position 4.

If I eliminate

```
--AND b.PrimaryID = b.SortOrder
```

then I get thousands of rows. I suspect something is wrong but it I am not understanding.  How can I make this simpler so it is REALLY easy to understand?

**IMPORTANT**: the `SortOrder` actually equals the `PrimaryID` if the data is no longer sorted. Otherwise it is incremental `1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ..` and so on. I guess this was the original architects way of doing it.

```
-- Merge data and get missing rows that have not changed.
SELECT 
    PrevPrimaryID = a.PrimaryID
    ,a.WidgetID
    ,a.AnotherValue
    ,a.DataID
    ,PrevSortOrder = a.SortOrder
    ,NewPrimaryID = b.PrimaryID
    ,NewDataID = b.DataID
    ,NewStartDate = b.StartDate
    ,NewSortOrder = b.SortOrder
INTO #NewOrder2
FROM #YesterdaysData2 a
LEFT JOIN #TodaysData2 b ON a.WidgetID = b.WidgetID
                         AND a.AnotherValue = b.AnotherValue
WHERE 
   a.Primaryid <> a.sortorder
   AND b.PrimaryID = b.SortOrder

SELECT * FROM #NewOrder2 

-- later update based on #NewOrder2...
UPDATE CustomerData
    SET SortOrder = (
        SELECT PrevSortOrder
        FROM #NewOrder2
        WHERE CustomerData.PrimaryID = #NewOrder2.NewPrimaryID
        )
    WHERE PrimaryID IN (
        SELECT NewPrimaryID
        FROM #NewOrder2
        )
```

UPDATE - Is it possible its just a blunder and the `WHERE` clause should be

```
WHERE a.Primaryid <> a.sortorder
AND b.PrimaryID <> b.SortOrder
```

Comment: How is `#TodaysData2` getting populated?  Does it have data in it?

Comment: @Andrew #TodaysData2 is being populated with a customData SELECT from non-temp tables and I have verified contains over 10,000 records.

Comment: is sortorder = null when a new record is created? why not check to see if the field is set and only sort it when it's null?

Comment: @KevinCook .. looking at the SPROC that Adds Data which runs 2X a day and the SPROC that Resets the SortOrder on Data.. it appears that a NULL Is in fact inserted. But why run the SPROCS at diff intervals?

Comment: that would probably be a business requirement of some sort. maybe they wanted to refresh the data every 12 hours?  that said, I would just check to see if sortorder is null (new record) and only update those and leave the rest alone until sortorder <> prevsortorder and then that meant the customer moved it around.